# Creating an Array that can input data

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create an array that can input data (up to 10 numbers - so slots: **0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9**, and whenever the user inputs the word "stop" it stops the user from inputting more data. However, if the maximum amount of inputs are used (all 10 slots), then the program stops the user from inputting any more numbers.

I'm starting with this:

```
int[] array;
array = new  int[10];

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input up to 10 numbers for the array: ");
```

I am pretty much stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Would this work?:

```
// while(!("stop".equals(scan)) || (array > 10)) {
// scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: @Jeremy While that does work it is "proper" to use a for loop

Comment: Hi @DanyalSandeelo, Sorry for another edit. When I input it, it doesn't look too organized. Can I just make a `System.out.println()` for each line? Like this? `System.out.println("1: ")` & `System.out.println("2: ")` ?

Comment: use this System.out.println((i+1)+": ");

Comment: One more edit, I promise, @DanyalSandeelo. How do you make it so the "stop" isn't in the lists of numbers. I don't want it in there.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, by the way! I am still a newbie learning Java, so this information is all so very helpful to my programming knowledge! :)

Comment: it wont be in the list because it breaks the loop when user types in stop (this is how i am doing in my code). You are using my code right?

Comment: Hm, for some reason the code `System.out.println("Input no longer taken. Array: /n" + array);` line isn't working. It's underlined in red.

Comment: @Jeremy this is not my code,, this is erroneous code, use my code..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, I rearranged the code because the number lists weren't showing up correctly. The second input became 1., the third input became 2.

Comment: what do you want actually? you want to print the inserted values?

Comment: Yeah, it looks a lot more organized that way, and I want the program to scan for the next integer because I don't want the user to input a letter and have that letter included within all the numbers within the list.

Comment: @Jeremy int array would never accept string input so this is impossible. As far as the printing is concerned use loop iteration to print the values.

Comment: @Jeremy run now. it would work now..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, Is there a way to implement the `scan.nextInt();` code in this program? Just curious.

Comment: it will work but would crash if you input string value because nextInt is for integers only...you can use if you consider 0 input value as the stopping case.. so the check would be like if (input==0) break; and instead of String input you would use int input.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, you are so helpful! Thank you so much. I will definitely remember your help.

Comment: @Jeremy anytime. Just message here if you need any help again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Input up to 10 numbers for the array: ");
 for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
   String input = scan.nextLine();
   if(input.equals("stop")) 
       break;
   else
       array[i]=Integer.valueOf(input);
 }
```

Comment: Where user is providing the input ??

Comment: @kick, I wrote this is a sort of pseudo + code..I would still edit it

Comment: Loop is running 9 times

Comment: you can use while and put a break inside the if else condition ... for greater than length of array and for the word stop

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
// Prints message
System.out.println("Input up to 10 numbers for the array: ");

int[] array = new int[10];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// Loops 10 times in total
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    // Use scan.nextLine() to get input from the user
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if(input.equals("stop")){

        System.out.println("Input no longer taken. Array: /n" + array);

         // Ends the loop
        break;
    }else{
        // Prints the current iteration of the array
        System.out.println((i+1)+": ");
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: The loop should run from i = 0  to i < 10.

Comment: How much time your loop is running ??

Comment: Previously your loop was running 9 times. Now you change it to 10.

Comment: @Kick well theres no harm in getting rid of a bug... I agnoledge i was wrong the first time

Comment: @ManOfPanda you copied mine :D it is okay though :D

Comment: `System.out.println("Input no longer taken. Array: /n" + array);` should be placed before the `break` so that it will be called

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Yours does too.... But its the general principal, not the details that counts :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        array = new  int[10];
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 10) {
        array[i] = scan.nextInt();
        i++;
        }
```

Comment: This does not fully answer the question.